# Laptop suddenly won't boot, lights and fan turn on but no other response

Tags: laptop

Day zero I take my laptop out of my room to stream a movie and find out it might as well not have a battery when it hibernates within a minute or two. When I plug it in and power it on, it comes up fine but a bit later it freezes. After a restart it's fine. After the movie, I have it hibernate to move it back. When I power it on, it blue screens, but after restarting it and dumping the hibernated state it comes up fine.

Day one, I use it as normal and have it sleep when I go out. When I get back, it won't wake up. The lights are on (front and button power light, caps lock, num lock, and battery if the battery is charging), but there is no display. I powered it off and when I start it again there is no change. The CD drive does open if I press that button.

I've tried booting with just AC or just battery, without HD and RAM, unplugging and removing battery then holding power (something about discharging static). Nothing changed what happens. I also tried plugging it in to an external monitor, but there was no video there either.

What I find really strange is when it is off, if I plug it in to AC, the fan turns on and the lights come on without me pressing any buttons.

The laptop is an Asus F81SE running Win 7 64 bit. I have it muted and turned off the boot sound, so I can't tell if it just isn't displaying anything. It's ancient but I don't use it enough to justify buying a new one. I contacted Asus, but they "determined the device requires a technician's attention and do not further troubleshoot the issue" but they don't have equipment and parts for EOL equipment.

Is there anything else I can try to fix it?

Update: I replaced the CMOS battery, which stopped it spontaneously turning on when I plug it in. But, it had no change otherwise - still no video (including on HDMI and VGA), num lock and caps lock lights stay on, no activity on a bootable flash drive

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot with a Linux Ubuntu Live USB.
If it boots fine, then the problem is probably with the disk.

To get more info about the failure using SMART data:

- Verify that `smartmontools` is installed. If not, use:

  ```
  apt-get install smartmontools
  ```
- Get the disk name (probably `/dev/sda`) from the list given by:

  ```
  fdisk -l
  ```
- Get a summary of the health status of the disk:

  ```
  smartctl --health /dev/sda
  ```
- For a more detailed output of all parameters, use:

  ```
  smartctl --all /dev/sda
  ```

If you need help understanding the SMART report, post it and let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't the screen show something when the HD is removed if this was the problem? I get the feeling it isn't POSTing.

Comment: If the Live USB won't boot, you are in trouble. Since the fan turns on, this is probably not a problem with the PSU. But that leaves CPU and motherboard and even RAM, so just hope this isn't the case.

Comment: No activity on the flash drive. I also tried a DVD, it sounds strange for a while (repeated seeking?) then spins normally, but still no display. Laptops normally show something when turning them on with no RAM, right?

Comment: This seems like a serious hardware error. I would suggest a repair-shop.

Comment: I replaced the CMOS battery, it no longer spontaneously turns on when I plug it in, but there was no other change when turning it on normally. I'll re-run some of the other tests this evening.

Comment: MemTest86 is a good all-around test but has long running times.